# Express-validator returning empty array of erros even when there are errors

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sequelize.js, express-validator

I am trying to validate user input with express validator and I get an empty array of errors which is incorrect because I sent the wrong input to test. When I console.log(errors), I get this : Result { formatter: [Function: formatter], errors: [] }

```
login = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    body("email").isEmail(), body("password").isLength({ min: 5 });
    const errors = validationResult(req);
    console.log(errors);
    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
      return res.status(400).json({ errors: errors.array() });
    }
    const user = await User.findOne({ where: { email: req.body.email } });
    if (!user) {
      return res
        .status(400)
        .json({ error_msg: "An account for this email does not exist" });
    }
    const validPass = await bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, user.password);
    if (!validPass) {
      return res.status(400).json({ error_msg: "E-mail or password is wrong" });
    }
    const token = await getSignedToken(user);
    return res.status(200).json({ token: token });
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(400).json({ error_msg: error.message });
  }
};
```

This is my sample input:
{
"email":"samadejoro",
"password":"sams"
}

Comment: can you provide test input you entered?

Comment: You should include the input , you are testing. Also, what are you passing in req? Add `validationResult` function in the question.

Comment: {
    "email":"samadejoro",
    "password":"sams"
} @SwapnilSoni

Comment: You need to add the validation pattern too. Like what are you validating? How are you validating?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by that? Can you explain better?